# linux + verify if file is text or binary

Tags: linux

How can I verify if the file is binary or text without to open the file?

Comment: It's hard to tell whether this is programming related or whether it should be migrated to SuperUser.com (is an existing utility sought after?).

Comment: Text is at best a subset of binary, if not merely an interpretation. Consider a one-byte file containing `0x65`. Now tell me absolutely if this is binary or text.

Comment: what about copying file before verify. copy -> open -> verify -> delete

Comment: @ralu: How are you going to copy a file without opening it?

Comment: @MSalters, Just wait till you see my ASCII encoded bitmap image format.

Comment: @MSalters You can in many cases tell absolutely whether the "binary" is in the "text subset".

Answer (score 10):

Schrödinger's cat, I'm afraid.

There is no way to determine the contents of a file without opening it. The filesystem stores no metadata relating to the contents.

If not opening the file is not a hard requirement, then there are a number of solutions available to you.

**Edit:**

It has been suggested in a number of comments and answers that `file(1)` is a good way of determining the contents. Indeed it is. However, `file(1)` *opens* the file, which was prohibited in the question. See the penultimate line in the following example:

```
> echo 'This is not a pipe' > file.jpg && strace file file.jpg 2>&1 | grep file.jpg
execve("/usr/bin/file", ["file", "file.jpg"], [/* 56 vars */]) = 0
lstat64("file.jpg", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=19, ...}) = 0
stat64("file.jpg", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=19, ...}) = 0
open("file.jpg", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE)  = 3
write(1, "file.jpg: ASCII text\n", 21file.jpg: ASCII text
```

Comment: The unix command file does a good job at heuristically determining the type

Comment: @Joel: Yes it does. It also opens the file.

Comment: The question is too vague to know if "open" means open(2). "Open" has other connotations.

Comment: True enough, @camh. I take 'open' to mean "examine the contents of" the file. Perhaps @lidia is interested in knowing whether a file on which the user has no read permissions is text or binary. 'file', etcetera would be of no use here.

Answer (score 7):

The correct way to determine the type of a file is to use the file(1) command.

You also need to be aware that UTF-8 encoded files are "text" files, but may contain non-ASCII data. Other encodings also have this issue. In the case of text encoded with a [code page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page), it may not be possible to unambiguously determine if a file is text or not.

The file(1) command will look at the structure of a file to try and determine what it contains - from the file(1) man page:

> The type printed will usually contain
>   one of the words ***text*** (the file
>   contains only printing characters and
>   a few common control characters and is
>   probably safe to read on an ASCII
>   terminal), ***executable*** (the file contains
>   the result of compiling a program in a
>   form understandable to some UNIX kernel
>   or another), or ***data*** meaning anything
>   else (data is usually ‘binary’ or non-printable).

With regard to different character encodings, the file(1) man page has this to say:

> If a file does not match any of the
>   entries in the magic file, it is
>        examined to see if it seems to be a text file.  ASCII, ISO-8859-x, non-
>        ISO 8-bit extended-ASCII character sets (such as those used on
>   Macintosh
>        and IBM PC systems), UTF-8-encoded Unicode, UTF-16-encoded
>   Unicode, and
>        EBCDIC character sets can be distinguished by the different ranges
>   and
>        sequences of bytes that constitute printable text in each set.
>   If a file
>        passes any of these tests, its character set is reported.  ASCII,
>        ISO-8859-x, UTF-8, and extended-ASCII files are identified as
>   ‘text’
>        because they will be mostly readable on nearly any terminal;
>   UTF-16 and
>        EBCDIC are only ‘character data’ because, while they contain text, it
>   is
>        text that will require translation before it can be read.

So, some text will be identified as **text**, but some may be identified as **character data**. You will need to determine yourself if this matters to your application and take appropriate action.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way of being certain without looking inside the file. Hoewever, you don't have to open it with an editor and see for yourself to have a clue. You may want to look into the `file` command: http://linux.die.net/man/1/file

Answer (score 2):

If you are attempting to do this from a command shell then the `file` command will take a guess at what filetype it is. If it is text then it will generally include the word text in its description.

I am not aware of any 100% method of determining this but the file command is probably the most accurate.

Comment: Indeed it does, although I wasn't sure whether he was averse to opening the file himself or having a utility open it. I have stated that there is no 100% certain method of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

In unix, a file is just some  bytes. So, without opening the file, you cannot figure out 100% that's it's ASCII or Binary.

You can just use tools available to you and dig deeper to make it fool proof.

1. file
2. cat -v